# Disable keyboard of mobile, when focused on html input field

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a progressive web app in angular. I want to add calling functionality, for which I have created my dialog box with numpad. I have used input tag of html to display number typed by user. 
I want to allow user to paste number on that textbox, or user can simply type numbers on numpad. 
I am accessing this application from mobile.
When I am trying to click on that textbox to perform "paste" operation, my mobile's keyboard pops in, which I don't want.

I found few suggestions like `BLUR` or `Dissable` or `Readonly` inputs. But these suggestion are not good for me, because I would like to type in  field by my numpad Keyboard.

I want to allow user to focus on textbox, yet don't want mobile's keyboard to pop in.

Would really appreciate if anyone can help with the solution. Thanks.

I have also tried cordova-plugin-keyboard to hide mobile's keyboard, but it didn't work.

```
<input id="input" type="text" onpaste="true;" [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber">
```

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to disable iOS keyboard. The expected behavior is for a user to be presented a keyboard whenever the option to type is made available by the app. If your app presents an input field and doesn’t also present a keyboard this would be confusing to the user, and be considered bad practice.

Comment: @Cybernetic I have created my keyboard below the <input> tag. I want to disable mobile's keyboard, at the same time want to allow user to paste number in <input> tag if he wants.